# Running IPython notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda and then Jupyter by writing `conda install jupyter`. When I try to open the notebook by writing `ipython3 notebook`, a page in my browser shows up with the following error:

> 404 : Not Found
>
> You are requesting a page that does not exist!

(In the browser's bar, there is *http://localhost:8888/tree* - don't know if that helps).
This is what my console is showing:

[image]

What am I missing? Do I need to change directory or set up anything?

Comment: What happens when before running `ipython3 notebook` you first `cd` to a different directory?

Comment: I used a different directory and it now works fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says "Refusing to serve hidden directory, via 404 error." This means that the directory you are in is hidden (begins with a `.`) If you change to a visible directory (one that does not begin with a `.`), it should open your notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I installed npm like sudo apt-get install npm and then everything was fine ..